# Fixed navigation add class depend of section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add class to header depend of section its by. here is my code

```css
.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    height:15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: orange;
}

section {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}

.first-section {
    background-color: black;
}

.second-section {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" class="navigation">menu</div>

<section class="first-section" id="a"></section>
<section class="second-section"  id="b"></section>
<section class="third-section" id="c"></section>
```

I guess I need some jQuery code to add class to `.navigation` when its bring to `.second-section` [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vachos/m03s32pL/12/)

Comment: You want to add a class to the header when the user scrolls into `second-section`? Correct?

Comment: yes that correct.

Comment: Are your sections going to be specific heights? If so you can use the jQuery in the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m03s32pL/14/

Comment: If not, then i recommend looking at this codepen for some answers: https://codepen.io/ChrisJohnson/pen/dIGDA

Comment: sorry no its not gonna be specific height. Thanks for help

Comment: Did you see the Codepen? You can use the jQuery provided there to detect when your `section` has bit the top of the `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a little with your code and finally came to this:

```js
function style_in_section(elementId, styleClassName, sectionClassName) {
  var pos = window.pageYOffset;
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var section = document.getElementsByClassName(sectionClassName)[0];
  if ((pos >= section.offsetTop) && (pos < section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight)) {
    element.classList.add(styleClassName);
  } else {
    element.classList.remove(styleClassName);
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  style_in_section("nav", "nav-black", "second-section");
  style_in_section("nav", "nav-gray", "third-section");
};
```

```css
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: white;
  color: orange;
}


/* I added styles here */

.nav-black {
  background: black;
}

.nav-gray {
  background: gray;
}

section {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.first-section {
  background-color: black;
}

.second-section {
  background-color: white;
}

.third-section {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" class="navigation">menu</div>
<section class="first-section" id="a"></section>
<section class="second-section" id="b"></section>
<section class="third-section" id="c"></section>
```

Is that the kind of things you want to achieve?
Note that I used vanilla JavaScript.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please make it "getElementsByClassName" and also give me code to add vanilla JavaScript in my header?

Comment: @Vachos Sure I could use `getElementsByClassName` instead, but are you going to have several `first-section` ?. And, what do you mean by "give me code to add vanilla JavaScript in my header?" ?

Comment: i must add the vanilla JavaScript  library to my website right?

Comment: my bad iam new in js. sorry .

Comment: @Vachos I already answered you with that: Sure I could use getElementsByClassName instead, but are you going to have several `first-section` ? Because I need to know if I'll need to handle several of the same sections in my code.

Comment: no i only have first-sectrion, second, third, etc. no double names. But sure i need class be removed after scroll out of section

Comment: Man you rock it! just one final think check here https://jsfiddle.net/vachos/m03s32pL/17/   i need when its go out of second-section the class wich added be removed. Sorry if i can explain correct.

Comment: @Vachos The problem with your fiddle is that you have 2 `first-section` in your html. It will work correctly if you remove the second one.

Comment: Yes sure i get that. But i basicly need to have one main section and some custom. So the class must be added and removed after scroll. Thanks for help.

Comment: when i scroll up of second-section the class removed. i need the same happen after scroll down of second-section. just final step ;-)

Comment: @Vachos I added what you wanted. I imagine it's going to be used and re-used, so I created a function of it. What do you think about that? :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m03s32pL/15/)

This adds the `selected` class to your nav when the user scrolls into `second-section`.

**JS:**

```
var target = $(".second-section").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
        $('#nav').addClass('selected');
    }
}, 0);
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Get the latest version of jQuery from [here](http://code.jquery.com/) - the fiddle uses jQuery version 3.3.1

**EDIT:**

Add this to your footer.php file in your Wordpress theme.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var target = $(".second-section").offset().top;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
            $('#nav').addClass('selected');
        }
    }, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: its look work fine in demo but in my website i have this error "$ is not a function. (In '$(".second-section")', '$' is undefined)"

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please grab the latest version of jQuery - 3.3.1

Comment: i still have the same error in my website. Can you give me a little more help? Your code is sort and looks fine. I use wordpress cms if this help

Comment: @Vachos - See my edit. If you add that to your footer.php and still see the `$ is not defined` in the console then let me know, however adding it like that should work with WP. Make sure you add the css to your style.css also!

Comment: ok its seems work fine. but i need to remove the class when scroll  its out of section. can you please update this to?